# mongodb query to find un matched data from two tables

Tags: mongodb

I have two tables storing news for national and international news media, and two tables storing their topical key phrases and news related information. I need to filter the data, to delete the topical key phrases from one table that are not present in other table. How can I write a query in mongodb to effectively remove not matching tokens. Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

token table1

```
"_id" : ObjectId("565f5aad6a650506d070453e"),
"Token" : "dominion",
"news_id" : "565f27ee6a65051ac86909dc"
```

token table2

```
"_id" : ObjectId("565c34fb6a650520f0bd21ee"),
"Token" : "charsadda",
"news_id" : "564b31b16a650518d80f9680"
```

I need to find dominion in token table2 if not present in second table than delete this document.

Comment: provide a rough schema to understand the problem better!

Comment: @Poorna i have cleared the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First find distinct values of 'Token' from first collection

```
tokens = db.temptoken1.distinct('Token')
```

Then pass these values to remove operation on table 2 with $nin condition

```
db.temptoken2.remove({Token: {$nin: tokens}})
```

Note: It will help if you add index on Token field